# React Re-render Component Does not work unless full page refresh occurs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that must be rendered a certain number of time based on a certain index, the problem is that when I use history.push to the same path with a change only in a variable in the path, the path changes but the component is not rendered unless I refresh the page , how can I solve this issue without using force refresh or refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your changed `variable` from path to your component's `props`. In this case `props` will be changed everytime path is changed and component will be re-rendered.